# Restify parsing XML in body of a request

Tags: node.js, xml, restify

Using [Restify](http://restify.com/), we want to receive a POST request with XML in the body.

I'm using `server.use(restify.bodyParser())`  to parse the body of requests, however the request comes in with `Content-Type: application/xml` and I'm not 100% sure this is the best way to deal with it.

```
myRestifyServer.post('/my/place/to/post/to', function (req, res, next) {
  var xml = req.body; // ?
  var myObject = myFavouriteXmlParser(xml)
// and so on...
})
```

However, req.body seems to contain and object with a `type` property and a `data` property - presumably the default action of bodyParser when it doesn't know what to do with something.

Is it possible to extend bodyParser in some way to accept `application/xml` and decode it, or would I have to create a new plugin to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

The bodyParser middleware cannot handle xml body data.
However, if you want to use it, you must use `bodyParser.raw([options])` or `bodyParser.text([options])` and give the returned data to a xml parsing library.

A better solution in your case is to use another middleware that handle requests that include xml body data.

Some examples:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser-xml
- https://github.com/macedigital/express-xml-bodyparser